# mysql query table join

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, GAMES and USERS set up with the following fields:

```
tblGAMES-->
GAME_ID (int) primary key,
P1_ID (int),
P2_ID (int),
P3_ID (int),
P4_ID (int)

tblUSERS-->
USER_ID (int) primary key,
FIRST_NAME (text),
LAST_NAME (text)
```

I am querying my database to print out the details of every game row. Example:

```
GAME_ID:1, P1:1, P2:2, P3:3, P4:4
```

but instead of printing out the id which is stored in tblGAMES I would like to print out the first name of each player as it appears in the corresponding row in tblUSERS. Is this doable using a single query as opposed to multiple queries?

```
end result-->GAME_ID:1, P1:David, P2:Paul, P3:John, P4:Bobby
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to join the users table 4 times...

```
select g.GAME_ID, 
       u1.FIRST_NAME as ulname, 
       u2.FIRST_NAME as u2name, 
       u3.FIRST_NAME as u3name, 
       u4.FIRST_NAME as u4name
from tblGAMES as g 
  left join tblUSERS as u1 on g.P1_ID =u1.USER_ID 
  left join tblUSERS as u2 on g.P2_ID =u2.USER_ID 
  left join tblUSERS as u3 on g.P3_ID =u3.USER_ID 
  left join tblUSERS as u4 on g.P4_ID =u4.USER_ID
```

(untested)

Answer (score 1):

In the query you're going to want to reference `tblUSERS` once per `JOIN`.  Something like this:

```
SELECT
    tblGAMES.GAME_ID,
    tblUSER1.FIRST_NAME AS P1,
    tblUSER2.FIRST_NAME AS P2,
    tblUSER3.FIRST_NAME AS P3,
    tblUSER4.FIRST_NAME AS P4
FROM tblGAMES
    INNER JOIN tblUSERS AS tblUSER1 ON tblGAMES.P1_ID = tblUSER1.USER_ID
    INNER JOIN tblUSERS AS tblUSER2 ON tblGAMES.P2_ID = tblUSER2.USER_ID
    INNER JOIN tblUSERS AS tblUSER3 ON tblGAMES.P3_ID = tblUSER3.USER_ID
    INNER JOIN tblUSERS AS tblUSER4 ON tblGAMES.P4_ID = tblUSER4.USER_ID
```

Note that my syntax may need a little tweaking, I haven't written enough MySQL recently to free-hand it 100% reliably.  But you get the idea.  Each join gets added to the overall product independently.

You may also change the `JOIN` types depending on how required each player is.  For example, if some games are 2-player then you'd want these to be `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s instead so as to better handle `null` values, etc.